# How many times and what all we can eat in Navratri?

Tags: culture, festivals, durga, vrata, navrathri

I want to know that how many times in a day we can eat when we are doing Navratri fast? Some are saying that we can have sattvik any number of times and some are saying two times. Please help me with correct method.

Comment: Similar question about fasting - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/27093/can-we-make-every-ekadashi-fast-as-nirjalaa-ekadashi

Comment: That question is for Ekadashi not Navratri.