# What are Rules and Hierarchy of Ekadashi Upavasa?

Tags: vishnu, ekadashi

Different websites, different rules are all over internet.

Common rules are of fasting. But what are the **scripture backed specific rules**??

Like should every Ekadashi be Nirjala Ekadashi or only Jyeshta Shukla Ekadashi be Nirjala Ekadashi? If so can you drink water on other Ekadashis? There are websites which says eating fruits is ok. What about sleep and sex during Ekadashi?  Are there hierarchies in different Ekadashis??

Also the breaking of fast or parana time needs some clarity. Its said you shouldn't do it on first quarter of dwadashi callerd Hari Vasara. It can also not be done on noon. So its must be either before 8:30 am or in the evening. But is this backed by scripture? What are the proper rules for parana?

So please answer with **rules for Ekadashi fasting and breaking fast on Dwadashi backed by authentic scripture**

Comment: [answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/27261/4435) without scripture-backed

Comment: @mar there are such answers all over the internet. But I want what the actual traditional scriptures say about fast and parana

Comment: while the answer doesn't have link to scriptures, most of it is def. based on scriptures & upanyasa of scholars.

Answer (score 1):

In [Skanda Purana](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc371691.html) the instructions about the ekadashi vrat are given;

> 21-25. I shall narrate that to you. I shall describe that splendid Udyāpana rite (valedictory rite after a Vrata). This splendid Vrata (named) Akhaṇḍa Ekādaśī Vrata should be performed on the Dvādaśī days, O excellent one among men, in Mārgaśīrṣa and other months.

> **On the Daśamī day he should have Naktabhojana. He should fast on the Ekādaśī day. On the Dvādaśī day he should take a single meal. This is called Akhaṇḍa. By the word Nakta we mean the eighth part of the day when the sun becomes very dim. Food is taken then and not at night.**

> One who is a devotee of Viṣṇu should avoid the following ten[3] on the Daśamī days: **(meal in) bell-metal vessels, meat, Masūra pulse, Caṇakas (chickpea), grain called Kodravas (Paspalum scrobiculatum), greens, honey, other men’s food, subsequent meal and sexual intercourse.**

> 26-27. This procedure is for the Daśamī day. Listen to that of Ekādaśī. The devotee of Viṣṇu should avoid these ten on the Ekādaśī day: **frequent drinking of water, violence, unclean habits, untruthfulness, chewing of betel leaves, twigs for brushing teeth, sleeping and having sexual intercourse during the day, playing game of dice, sleeping during night and conversation with fallen persons.**